# Convert SQL query to Doctrine 1.2 dql

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine-1.2

I have a select query in Mysql table to fetch related table with a duplicate values in a specific column(date).This will successfully display columns and its foreign keys if it has duplicate values in a column.Example two rows same value of (2014-11-10) in a date column

```
mysql>select man_id,date_created,count(date_created) as count
from collections
group by man_id,date_created
having count(date_created) > 1;
```

I want this query to convert to Doctrine query since I am using symfony 1.4 as a framework

```
 public function getDuplicateDatePayment() {
    $q = $this->createQuery()
              ->select('man_id','date_created','count(date_created) as count')
              ->from('Collections')
              ->groupBy('man_id','date_created')
              ->having('COUNT(c.date_created) > 1');
        return $q->execute();
}

SELECT c.id AS c__id, c.man_id AS c__man_id FROM collections c GROUP BY c.man_id HAVING count(c.date_created) > 1 //result 1 row
```

why does doctrine query does not display results as expected?How to convert said doctrine query so that it will display result similar to SQL?

[image: mysql command line]

//result 1141 rows

update

Collections table is related to Man table in a one to many relationship.Do i have to use innerJoin for this?

Comment: "why does doctrine query does not display results as expected" --- they have different `GROUP BY`, that's why

Comment: They are still different

Answer (score 0):

After two days of trying,searching for an answer, I finally found a solution to my problem.

```
SELECT c.id AS c__id, c.man_id AS c__man_id FROM collections c GROUP BY c.man_id HAVING count(c.date_created) > 1
```

The problem of above sql result from doctrine is ,it does not include 'c.loan_id' in groupBy clause,even though I include it in groupBy clause.The solution is ,just add a separated addGroupBy clause ..And now its working.cheers..

```
public function getDuplicateDatePayment() {
$q = $this->createQuery()
          ->select('c.man_id','c.date_created','count(c.date_created) as count')
          ->from('Collections')
          ->groupBy('c.man_id')
          ->addGroupBy('c.date_created')
          ->having('count(c.date_created) > 1');
    return $q->execute();
```

}